# QUERY SUMA DE TAREAS

Tags: sql

Estoy creando un reporte con un query que creé, pero quiero ver si existe alguna otra forma que me de el mismo resultado sin que este tan largo.

Este es mi query. Ahora me arroja el porcentaje de tareas realizadas por mes en un rango de fechas que elijo.

```sql
SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 1 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS ENERO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 1 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM ENERO', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 1 AND  A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 1 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM ENERO',


SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 2 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS FEBRERO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 2 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM FEBRERO', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 2 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 2 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM FEBRERO',


SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 3 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS MARZO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 3 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM MARZO', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 3 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 3 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM MARZO',



SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 4 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS ABRIL',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 4 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM ABRIL', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 4 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 4 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM ABRIL',


SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 5 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS MAYO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 5 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM MAYO', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 5 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 5 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM MAYO',


SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 6 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS JUNIO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 6 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM JUNIO', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 6 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 6 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM JUNIO',


SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 7 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS JULIO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 7 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM JULIO', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 7 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 7 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM JULIO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 8 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS AGOSTO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 8 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM AGOSTO', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 8 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 8 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM AGOSTO',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 9 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS SEPTIEMBRE',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 9 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM SEPTIEMBRE', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 9 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 9 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM SEPTIEMBRE',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 10 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS OCTUBRE',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 10 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM OCTUBRE', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 10 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 10 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM OCTUBRE',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 11 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS NOVIEMBRE',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 11 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM NOVIEMBRE', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 11 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 11 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM NOVIEMBRE',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 12 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS DICIEMBRE',

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 12 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM DICIEMBRE', 

SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 12 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 AND A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) * 100 /NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(A.Due_Date) = 12 AND A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END),0)  as 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM DICIEMBRE'

FROM Maintenance_v_Work_Request_e A
WHERE A.Due_Date between @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puesto que estás mostrando 3 columnas por mes, siempre vas a tener que excribir las 36 columnas. Pero podemos evitar repetir cálculos.

Primero, pasamos `A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54` a la clausula `WHERE`, así aparece sólo una vez en vez de 48.

Después, hacemos un agregado agrupando por mes, así reducimos las fórmulas para tenerlas sólo una vez y sólo hacemos mención a su nombre.

Al final, sólo nos queda hacer la transposición de filas a columnas usando sólo el mes.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT MONTH(A.Due_Date) AS Mes,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 END) AS MantenimientoPMCerradas,
           COUNT(*) AS TotalMantenimientoPM,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN A.Work_Request_Status_Key = 49 THEN 1 END) * 100. / NULLIF( COUNT(*), 0) AS Porcentaje
    FROM Maintenance_v_Work_Request_e A
    WHERE A.Due_Date between @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
    AND   A.Work_Request_Type_Key = 54 
    GROUP BY MONTH(A.Due_Date)
)
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 1  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS ENERO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 1  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM ENERO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 1  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM ENERO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 2  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS FEBRERO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 2  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM FEBRERO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 2  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM FEBRERO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 3  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS MARZO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 3  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM MARZO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 3  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM MARZO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 4  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS ABRIL',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 4  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM ABRIL',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 4  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM ABRIL',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 5  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS MAYO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 5  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM MAYO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 5  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM MAYO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 6  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS JUNIO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 6  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM JUNIO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 6  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM JUNIO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 7  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS JULIO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 7  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM JULIO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 7  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM JULIO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 8  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS AGOSTO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 8  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM AGOSTO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 8  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM AGOSTO',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 9  THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS SEPTIEMBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 9  THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM SEPTIEMBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 9  THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM SEPTIEMBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 10 THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS OCTUBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 10 THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM OCTUBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 10 THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM OCTUBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 11 THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS NOVIEMBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 11 THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM NOVIEMBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 11 THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM NOVIEMBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 12 THEN MantenimientoPMCerradas ELSE 0 END) AS 'MANTENIMIENTO PM CERRADAS DICIEMBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 12 THEN TotalMantenimientoPM    ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MANTENIMIENTO PM DICIEMBRE',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 12 THEN Porcentaje              ELSE 0 END) AS 'PORCENTAJE REALIZADO MANTENIMIENTO PM DICIEMBRE'
FROM CTE;
```